# What is $(0) and $(1) used for in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

While reading the following performance test, I noticed the author used `$(0)` and `$(1)`. What is the purpose of this?

http://jsperf.com/scriptjunkie-premature-3

```
var $a = $(0);

function fn_1() {
 var $a = $(this);
 if ($a.attr("rel") == "foo") {
  $a.addClass("foo");
 }
 else {
  $a.addClass("other");
 }
}

function fn_2() {
 $a.context = $a[0] = this; // fake the collection object
 if ($a.attr("rel") == "foo") {
  $a.addClass("foo");
 }
 else {
  $a.addClass("other");
 }
}
```

Comment: Whatever this behavior is, it's undocumented. `$(0) => []` and `$(1) => [1]` (and `$(2) => [2]`), but I have no idea why :/

Comment: Have you read the article this test links to?

Comment: Thanks @FelixKling, I didn't notice there is a link ! I was first reading [this](https://docs.google.com/present/view?id=0Ac0YlG9vMA2LZHE1MnpycF8yMGZ6ZnZxa2hy&pli=1) =]

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [jQuery source code](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js), you can see that `init` is called when `$()` is executed. This function contains several `if` statements to handle various pieces of information passed as the selector. At the end of the function the following is called:

```
return jQuery.makeArray( selector, this );
```

If a number such as `1` or `2` is passed, the call to `makeArray` will just convert it to an array such as `[1]`, `[2]`, etc. So there is nothing particularly special about `$(1)`.

Comment: So what is the purpose of it...? Why not `$a = $()` or `$a = $(true)` or `$a = [1]`?